# childviewcontrollers transparency in containerviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, childviewcontroller

I have two `childViewController`s **X** & **Y** added to a `parentViewController` **A**.

The views of **X** & **Y** are added to **A** as `subView`s.

- **X** has a `UILabel`
- **Y** has an `UIImageView`
- (*and I have many other views as `subView`s for X & Y in my project*).

`X.view` is on top of `Y.view` and I can change the `alpha`, `opacity` or `backgroundColor` of these as I desire.

---

I want **X**'s background to be transparent but the `UILabel` on it should be `opaque` and seen on top of **Y**'s `UIImageview`.

To achieve this, I tried it multiple ways, but didnt work, such as:

1. set clear color as `backgroundColor` to `X.view`

   - but it appears black rather than showing the underneath `Y.view`.
2. Set opacity for `X.view.layer` < 1 and `opaque=NO`

   - I can see `Y.view` underneath it but the `UILabel` on **X**'s view is also becoming dull.
3. Tried setting mask to **X**'s layer

   - but the black background on **X**'s view is not going away.
4. tried setting `allowsGroupOpacity` and `shouldRastorize`.

   - This doesnt help, as the purpose of them may be for a different context.

Hope I am clear.
Thanks for looking at it.